# Project output files deleting when rebuilding entire VS solution, causing build failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Before building anything, here is the output folder of the problematic project:
[image]
It is empty

After building the whole solution, I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0006  Metadata file
> 'C:\Users\Grant\Source\Repos\raderag\ExcelConnectRTDKraken\KrakenOrderSystem\bin\x86\Debug\KrakenOrderSystem.dll'
> could not be
> found KrakenOrderTestClient   C:\Users\Grant\Source\Repos\raderag\ExcelConnectRTDKraken\KrakenOrderTestClient\CSC 1   Active

Which makes sense, because there is nothing in that folder. So I rebuild the problematic project by itself, and the rebuild is successful. The output folder looks like this:

[image]
All dlls are there. So far so good

Now when I try to rebuild the entire project, I get the same exact error as before and the files in that output file are gone.

Here's what I've tried:

I rebuilt the problematic project successfully. I then rebuilt every single project in the solution one by one to see if they would delete the files in that project output. None of them did. I then tried rebuilding the whole solution, and got the same error with the output files gone.

Sorry that I don't have more information. Please let me know what more I can provide to accelerate a solution to my problem. Thank you!

Edit:
Oddly enough, the rebuild of the entire solution actually sometimes works. It doesn't always delete those files, although 90 percent of the time it does, and I can't find the cause for it's success and failure. It's seemingly random.

Edit:
Even more absurdly, without changing anything the solution now successfully builds 90 percent of the time and fails for the same reason 10 percent of the time.

Comment: It sounds like you need to setup some dependencies to force that project to build first.

Comment: @RetiredNinja what would cause the need for this though? Is Visual studio not smart enough to build it first to avoid any dependency issues? Only 1 other project is referencing this one, and its referencing it directly from the Projects tab in reference manager.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Also, the project that references the problematic one successfully builds when there are no files in the output of the problematic project it references. It actually adds the needed files to the problematics output, meaning its building the problematic project that its referencing. This tells me that visual studio already has the depency issue handled.

Comment: It seems to me if it was smart enough to figure it out automatically you wouldn't be asking this question. Just a suggestion. Maybe it helps, maybe not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I did not mean that comment sarcastically. Poor choice of words. My apologies. Visual studio does seem to build the project it references first when I tested it.